# Multiple find_by attributes gives undefined method for nil:NilClass error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Trying to use `find_by` to find by 2 columns but I get a no method error.

The first 2 work fine but the third with finding by 2 columns gives the error `undefined method 'key' for nil:NilClass`

```
CategoryItemValue.find_by(key: key).key #works fine

CategoryItemValue.find_by(category_item_id: item_id).key #works fine

CategoryItemValue.find_by(key: key, category_item_id: item_id).key #error
```

I'm using rails 4 and though this was possible?

Comment: check you are not getting value due to that it is giving error

Comment: Your first two lines constitute `A || B`. Your 3rd line is `A && B`. They are not the same.

Comment: I know, I made a mistake of not saving the DB when I added the new data. It works fine now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are no records matching the condition.
Try:

```
CategoryItemValue.find_by(key: key, category_item_id: item_id).try(:key)
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out I forgot to save the DB after I put data into it. So if I use .try it wont give the error if there are no records matching? Or is that for something else